# Pact-broker connection to Azure Postgres database is failing

Tags: azure-aks, pact

Issue: Deployed pactfoundation\pact-broker docker image to AKS(Azure Kubernetes) Cluster and am using Azure postgres database. Connectivity to postgres database is failing, can't seem to understand Puma it's trying to connect as root user. Here's the log extract:

Puma starting in single mode...

- Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
- Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
- Environment: production
  ! Unable to load application: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
  bundler: failed to load command: puma (/pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:210:in `initialize' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:210:in` new'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:210:in `connect' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:122:in` make_new'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:209:in `assign_connection' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:139:in` acquire'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:91:in `hold' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:269:in` synchronize'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:278:in `test_connection' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/database/misc.rb:169:in` initialize'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in `new' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in` connect'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.40.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:124:in `connect' /pact_broker/database_connection.rb:31:in` create_database_connection_from_config'
  config.ru:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pact_broker-2.76.2/lib/pact_broker/app.rb:39:in` initialize'
  config.ru:12:in `new' config.ru:12:in` block in '
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in` new_from_string'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in` parse_file'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:320:in `load_rackup' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:245:in` app'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/runner.rb:147:in `load_and_bind' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in` run'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in` run'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>' /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in` load'
  /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"

This tells me you are attempting to authenticate the Pact Broker application with Postgres use the `root` user, and either the credentials are incorrect or the user doesn't exist.

See also how to set the credentials on the container here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-broker-docker#configure-the-connection-details